# Social media share buttons don't redirect back to fan page iframe product page

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, addthis

A friend of mine added a store to my fan page that uses the iframe...basically putting a website inside a facebook frame. It has a SSL certificate. We added social media like buttons to each product page by using addthis.com code. See below. The code below works on the product page, however the problem is when you share it to facebook or google+, the link that is provided for that product, when clicked, takes the user to the hosting url where the zencart resides.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "zencart1/images/" . $products_image; ?>" />

<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" glusone:size="medium"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true}; </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-501a85992fdcfe86"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Fan Page: https://www.facebook.com/TracyLoganDesigns
Go to the category Scarves - this is where I have a test product.
When you click on the product test link once it's been shared on facebook, etc, this is the link it goes to: http://firetreegraphics.com/zencart1...9#.UBrFH01lTjY

How can I set it up so that it will go back to the fan page url?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set it up so that it will go back to the fan page url?

By not liking/sharing the product page hosted on your server, but the Facebook URL of your `/page/app` combination.

If you want to link to a *specific* product page inside of your app on Facebook (and not just the start page), then you have to use the `app_data` parameter inside of that link, and get it’s from the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter once your app is loaded into the iframe on Facebook.

Comment: So where would I put this in the code I have above? And how would it look? I have very little coding experience so spelling it out would be great! :)